# createjs, animating a line with x1,y1 and x2,y2 coordinates

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, createjs, easeljs

[image]

As shown in the image, there are two circles connected by a line, I can animate the circle position by `createjs.Tween.get(circleOne).to({x: someCoord, y:anotherCoord},1000)`.

I would like to update the line end points the similar way so that when the circles animate and move their ways the line end points stay attached to the circles.

The line is made by `line.graphics.beginStroke("red").setStrokeStyle(2).moveTo(20,20)`.

Thanks!!

Comment: If you used SVG instead and made this a line which had circle markers on then the markers would move automatically with the line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a better way to do this than what @tiago suggested: [Graphic Commands](http://blog.createjs.com/new-command-approach-to-easeljs-graphics/). You can update the values of commands that Graphics use any time by storing off the `command`.

Here is a quick demo, where I tween 2 circles, and on the "update" event of the first tween, I update the line command values to the circle coordinates.
http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/2xoL08bx/

**Example:**

```
var cmd = shape.graphics.lineTo(10,10).command;
cmd.x = 20; // Changes the x of the lineTo command that is stored off.
```

You can also tween a command's properties:

```
createjs.Tween.get(cmd).to({x: 100, y:100}, 1000);
```

When a command's values change, they will draw with the new values the next time the stage is updated. You can see a list of the commands and their values in the [EaselJS docs](http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Graphics.LineTo.html).

Comment: Lanny, how does using `command` with TweenJS compares to creating a whole new graphics instruction per frame, in terms of performance?

Comment: The cost is just the creation in code (and related GC of disposing objects). The stage has to be redrawn in either case. The command approach is just way is just more readable, as well as a better code practice, since you are only managing a property of list graphic instruction, which can be tweened or changed easily, instead of a bunch of separate properties that require the whole instruction list to be redrawn if changed.

Comment: Additionally, you can use this approach to reuse graphics commands via `append()`. In this example, each line is a quadratic curve. The `qt()` command is reused to draw an orange line, and then another smaller black line. http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/n1du0tew/10/

Answer (score 1):

Every time the circles move you'll need to redraw the line by clearing the old graphics instructions and creating a new one in place, without TweenJS. Notice that this will be very expensive since you'll not gain any benefits from caching.

Here's a line from coordinates `{x: 20, y: 20}` to `{x: 40, y: 40}`:

```
line.graphics.beginStroke("red").setStrokeStyle(2).moveTo(20,20).lineTo(40, 40);
```

Now if you want to change the end points to `{x: 10, y: 10}` to `{x: 50, y: 50}` you'll need to use:

```
line.graphics.clear();
line.graphics.beginStroke("red").setStrokeStyle(2).moveTo(10,10).lineTo(50, 50);
```

Remember that using `line.cache(x, y, w, h);` after the movement is highly recommended because it'll save the processor from drawing that line every frame unnecessarily.

Comment: Yeah, I was redrawing the whole line again with moveTo and I didnt like it and hence was looking for a better straightforward solution. Your answer confirms that there is nothing else I can do, Thank you!